# Cell Template with Hyperlink usage in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, hyperlink, icommand

I'm tring to insert an hyperlink within a `DataGrid` and find a method in order to implement the `RequestNavigate` behaviour using the MVVM pattern.

I've tried a lot of solutions up until now, but none of them works. Could you help me, please?

This is my xaml code:

```
<dgWPFCtrl:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Link to XXX"  Width="*">
                    <dgWPFCtrl:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock >
                                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=ID_HTTP_LINK}"
                                           >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID_HTTP_LINK}"/>
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RequestNavigate">
                                            <WPFCtrl:EventToCommand 
                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                Command="{Binding Path=OpenLinkCommand}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dgWPFCtrl:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dgWPFCtrl:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and following the relative `ICommand` development:

```cs
//Command for open link
RelayCommand _openLinkCommand;
public ICommand OpenLinkCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_openLinkCommand == null)
            _openLinkCommand = new RelayCommand(param => 
            {
                //Command Body ...
            });
        return _openLinkCommand;
    }
}
```

Where I'm wrong? Unexpectedly, the `ICommand` is never even called!

I've tried to use also other kind of event ( such as `MouseEnter`), but nothing changed!

Thanks in advance for your contributions,

Deby

Comment: Is the OpenLinkCommand located in the object being represented by the DataRow, or is the command in your ViewModel?

Comment: Actually it's in my ViewModel...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hyperlink's DataContext is that of the object represented by the DataGridRow, not your ViewModel.  So you'll have to use a binding method to get you to that ViewModel (either RelativeSource AncestorType, or ElementName).

**ElementName (assuming your DataGrid is named 'myDataGrid')**

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid, Path=DataContext.OpenLinkCommand}"
```

**RelativeSource**

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.OpenLinkCommand}"
```

Comment: dude, and I am digging web why my hyperlinks not working. Even I applied same method like 1 scroll down, could not see it.